# I need to repeat a VBA code for rows 5-200 and have no idea how what to do

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I need to repeat a VBA code for rows 5-200 and have no idea how to do it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$L$5" Then
       Range("M5:N5").Value = "Please Select..."

    ElseIf Target.Address = "$M$5" Then
       Range("N5").Value = "Please Select..."

   End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If Target.Address = "$L$5" Then 
        Range("M5:N5").Value = "Please Select..." 
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$M$5" Then 
        Range("N5").Value = "Please Select..." 
    For i = 1 To 10 
        Total = Total + iArray(i) 
    Next i 
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You're looking `for` a loop. Search `for loop vba`.

Comment: Yes, I have been researching that and am having issues implementing it.  :(

Comment: @urdearboy I have a spreadsheet that has 3 dependent drop downs and the current VBA code is only working for row 5 and I need to to repeat for rows 6-200 as well.

Comment: You don't need a loop, you can use ```target.row``` and ```target.column``` to determine if they are in the range you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for columns L and M on rows between 5 and 200. If you need other columns or rows just adjust the `If Statements`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row >= 5 And Target.Row <= 200 Then
        If Target.Column = 12 Then
            Range("M" & Target.Row & ":N" & Target.Row).Value = "Please Select..."
        ElseIf Target.Column = 13 Then
            Range("N" & Target.Row).Value = "Please Select..."
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked!  Thank you sooooooooo much!! :)  I have accepted your answer, but I am new, so I have less than 15 reputation, so my vote is recorded, but not publicly posted. :)